# Create multiple jars based on multiple packages with Maven

Tags: maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I want to create multiple jars in one maven project. The number of jars that would be generated is not known explicitly. It depends on the number of some packages.

I found how to create a jar with `maven-jar-plugin` based on explicity pointed package

```
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>com/processor/plugin/**</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

But in my case, the names of packages under `com.processor.plugin` are not known.

XProcessor and XProcessorProvider form a jar.

```
| com   
  | processor
    | plugin
      | first 
        | FirstProcessor.java
        | FirstProcessorProvider.java
      | second
        | SecondProcessor.java
        | SecondProcessorPorvider.java
      | third
        | ThirdProcessor.java
        | ThirdProcessorProvider.java
```

Expected result of `mvn package`:
first.jar, second.jar, third.jar

Is it possible at all?

What is the cause of these maybe strange requirements?
I'm going to use ServiceLoader which requires jar(s) with `META-INF/service/ProcessorProvider` file. But this would be solved with http://metainf-services.kohsuke.org/

Comment: I see why you want a jar per package but why can't you create a module for each jar you want in this case?

Comment: What do you mean "create a module for each jar"? maven module?

Comment: Yes, dynamically, if necessary.

Comment: +1 for turning these into separate Maven modules. I'm not sure if it's possible at all what you actually asked, nor should you care. Maven is about *convention over configuration*, and you're trying to swim upstream. As a rule of thumb, you should create as many modules as needed to keep functional areas separated and (this applies to you) to be able to independently deploy your units.